# Proxychains+Tor+Remmina RDP

Tags: proxy

Just picked up Kali, little rusty with linux. Im attempting to use Proxychains/Tor to log into my remote windows server over RDP(Remmina Application)

Proxychains by default uses Socks4 Tor connections it seems in the .conf file, so would I need to run Tor browser before initiating Proxychains?

Also, the command line for using Proxychains is like so 
user@kali:~$ proxychains application targethost.com

but doing
user@kali:~$ proxychains remmina
just brings up remmina gui, will the applications connections be proxied over Tor?

There's not been much mention on the internet of using both programs together, and there are no guides, any input would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Don't use proxychains, it fails open (leaks if something goes wrong). Kali linux users are insane.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the default value for the SOCKS port in the proxychains config file is currently 9050. If you open the TOR Browser it uses port 9150 (you can check this with netstat). So this won't work out of the box. But if you run TOR standalone without TBB it opens on port 9050. You should be able to install TOR on Debian-based distros simply with

```
sudo apt-get install tor
```

It then most likely already runs as service. If not start it with

```
tor
```

Then you can use proxychains. But the reliability of proxychains is often questioned (regarding e.g. DNS or UDP). You probably should use torsocks or torify as these options were designed to protect against e.g. DNS leaks. Usage is pretty much the same as with proxychains:

```
torsocks application parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

To launch Tor you need either launch your Tor Browser - or just a standalone Tor process, whatever you prefer: in both cases the `tor` binary will start and provide you with a SOCKS proxy, because Tor Browser actually launches a tor standalone binary. you will be fine *if the Tor proxy is the first in proxychains list* and don't forget to use dns-over-proxy name resolution. If you launch some binary like `proxychains command` - it's fine, proxychains used to control all the spawned threads as far as I remember.